# Synchronize UIView animation with keyboard animation

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, keyboard

I have a `UIView` that will change its `height` and position depending so it's always "stuck" to the keyboard. The problem is that there is a `asynchronous` animation when changing the `textField`, the rest works fine. Here is a video for a better understanding:

[Animation](https://gofile.io/?c=0kpgp6)

This happen even though I used `UIResponder.keyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey` for the animations.

Here are all the parts inside my code where I `animate`:

**Notification-Handler in `ViewController`:**

```
var keyboardHeight = CGFloat(0)
var duration: Any?
var curve: NSNumber?
//MARK: keyboardWillShow
@objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let keyboardFrame: NSValue = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
        let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
        self.keyboardHeight = keyboardRectangle.height

        let duration = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey]
        self.duration = duration
        let curve = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey]
        self.curve = curve as? NSNumber

        if self.wishViewIsVisible {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: self.duration as! TimeInterval, delay: 0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions(rawValue: UIView.AnimationOptions.RawValue(truncating: self.curve!)), animations: {
                        self.wishConstraint.constant = -(self.wishView.frame.height + self.keyboardHeight)
                        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                    }, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

**Closure-Handler in `ViewController`:**

```
self.wishView.onPriceButtonTapped = { [unowned self] height, isHidden in

        if isHidden {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: self.duration as! TimeInterval, delay: 0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions(rawValue: UIView.AnimationOptions.RawValue(truncating: self.curve!)), animations: {
                self.wishConstraint.constant -= height
                self.wishView.priceTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: nil)

        } else {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: self.duration as! TimeInterval, delay: 0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions(rawValue: UIView.AnimationOptions.RawValue(truncating: self.curve!)), animations: {
                self.wishConstraint.constant += height
                self.wishView.wishNameTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: nil)
        }  
    }
```

**Closure inside `UIView`:**

```
@objc func priceButtonTapped(){

    let priceViewIsHidden = priceView.isHidden

    if priceViewIsHidden {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
            self.priceView.alpha = 1
            self.priceView.isHidden = false
            self.theStackView.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
        self.onPriceButtonTapped?(priceView.frame.height, true)
    } else {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
            self.priceView.alpha = 0
            self.priceView.isHidden = true
            self.theStackView.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
        self.onPriceButtonTapped?(priceView.frame.height, false)

    }
}
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this issue?

I know I am hard-coding the `values` inside the `UIView` but that is just to hide/show the `arrangedSubview` inside the `StackView` and this is not where the animation is off as you can see in the video. It only looks off when changing the `textFields`.

Comment: Have you tried subscribing to `keyboardWillChangeFrame` notification, and adjusting at that point? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621623-keyboardwillchangeframenotificat

Comment: Chris I do not see any issue with the animation even in video. Can you please explain a little bit more where exactly is the issue?

Comment: @Manoj there is a small gap between the view and the keyboard when changing the textfield

Comment: @Manoj you can see it in the end of the video two times pretty good

Comment: @PeteMorris I have not tried that, because `keyboardWillShow` also fires when then `keyboard` changes. I just tried it

Comment: @PeteMorris Morris, I tried it out with `keyboardWillChangeFrame` but same result..